# Porting of linux on beagle bone black

Tags: linux

I am porting Linux on Beaglebone black. But while booting kernel doesn't get booted. The MLO and U-boot get booted properly. I copied zImage on the boot partition.
The steps that I have followed for the kernel cross compilation are below.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/Supriya/BeagleboneBlack/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.08_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- beaglebone_defconfig

$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/supriya/BeagleboneBlack/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.08_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage dtbs

$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/supriya/BeagleboneBlack/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.08_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- modules
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
output : Importing environment from mmc ...
** File not found /BOOT/zImage **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
SD/MMC found on device 1
reading uEnv.txt
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
** File not found /BOOT/zImage **
## Error: "nandboot" not defined
U-Boot#
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you're missing `uEnv.txt` amongst other things.  Here's a link that may help: http://www.twam.info/hardware/beaglebone-black/u-boot-on-beaglebone-black